# 503 server response for Googlebot

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I put an .htaccess file in my webroot with the following contents

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Googlebot|Googlebot|Mediapartners|Adsbot|Feedfetcher)-?(Google|Image)? [NC]
RewriteRule .* /var/www/503.html
```

This website is in maintenance mode, and I don't want anything indexed yet. I tested the code with a firefox User-Agent switcher plugin, and looking at the access log it shows this at the end of each log entry, but watching in TamperData or Firebug, it still returns a 200 server response instead of a 503. What am I doing wrong?

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

contents of /var/www/503.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>503 - Service temporary unavailable</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>503 - Service temporary unavailable</h1>
<p>Sorry, this website is currently down for maintainance please
retry later</p>
</body>
</html>
```

:::EDIT::: 
Added small snippet from the rewrite.log
    Here is a small sample, I went thru the entire log, and everything is referring to a javascript or image file:

```
172.16.173.26 - - [15/Jun/2010:15:03:31 --0500] [qa-test.com/sid#2b6c1c8ba938][rid#2b6c24cfdd18/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/qa-test.com/web/] RewriteCond: input='' pattern='^.*(Googlebot|Googlebot|Mediapartners|Adsbot|Feedfetcher)-?(Google|Image)?' [NC] => not-matched
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `503.php`? Maybe something is preventing the correct header from being output.

Comment: I updated my 503 page, the path, and the original post to show the error I am getting. I will put LogLevel debug to see what happens now.

Comment: Google only indexes content that is linked to from another site (and from there it crawls the links within your site) or manually submitted to their index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop. The result of your rewrite is being rewritten again.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (?:Googlebot|Googlebot|Mediapartners|Adsbot|Feedfetcher)-?(?:Google|Image)? [NC]
RewriteCond $0 !(?:^|/)503\.html$
RewriteRule .* /var/www/503.html [R=503]
```

As @BalusC pointed out, you also need the `R` flag.

Comment: I changed the .htaccess file to exactly what you put above. I am not receiving an error anymore, but it's not loading my 503.html file, it's loading the 503 coming soon. And the user agent in the apache log still says Googlebot.

Comment: @Hallik Post your rewritelog with rewriteloglevel 9.

Comment: I have updated the original post to include the relevant line in the rewrite.log. I verified in the access_log it shows Googlebot as the useragent.

Comment: @Hallik The IP is of a reserved private range. Are you sure it was the Google bot?...

Comment: I am testing this locally using a UserAgent Switcher in firefox to mimic the Googlebot

Comment: @Hallik well, your log entry suggests `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` is expanding to nothing. No idea why that might be happening.

Answer (score 1):

Either use:

```
RewriteRule .* /var/www/503.html [R=503,L]
```

Or when you're not on Apache 2.x yet where the above construct is supported, then make it a `503.php` page and set in top of code:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable");
```